# What global names are available in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, scope

Why some HTML elements are available as javascript global variables and other elements are not?

Why an input element is visible as global variable only if it is outside of a form?

With this simple page:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="form1">
      <input id='input1' />
      <div id='div1'></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have both `div1` and `input1` as global variables in Chrome, but in IE10 I `input1` is undefined: http://jsfiddle.net/M5ExX/

If I remove the form and leave the div and the input, then both are defined, both in Chrome and in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/M5ExX/1

Comment: HTML element IDs and global variables in JS are very different things. I'm having trouble figuring out what you're asking here.

Comment: I load the page, then I type `input1` or `div1` in the javascript console of the browser. The javascript global variables are automatically created using the element IDs.

Comment: Ahh, ok. In that case, the behavior is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3434388/1655495)

Comment: Thanks, it's clearer now, even if it doesn't answer the question why that `input1` becomes a global variable when outside a form and not when inside. Chrome is consistent, but IE (which started this!) only creates the global when it likes.